# Getting parameters out of http call in entity framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, http

Hi guys I am trying to use entity framework. I built my scaffolding andgot it to work. Right now it returns a list of my samples. However, I want it to know paging and I am not sure how to get parameters from the requests.

So for instance instead of calling api/Samples I would like to call api/Samples?size=3

I cant seem to get it to work.

```
    // GET: api/Samples
    [HttpGet] 
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Samples>>> GetSample(HttpRequestMessage req)
    {

        //I keep trying to use statements like this.
        //string size = req.RequestUri.Query["size"];

        var list = _context.Sample.AsQueryable();
       

        return await list.Take(Int32.Parse(size)).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: What does "I cant seem to get it to work." mean?

Comment: I cant figure out how to get it to query parameters out of the request.

Comment: This was what I have tried and it does not work